# Is the radiation problem actually solved in the classical quantum model of hydrogen?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, quantum-electrodynamics, hydrogen

It's often said that in classical physics a electron-proton system is not stable due to "Bremsstrahlung" and that one instead has to look at it quantum mechanically.

This doesn't make sense to me. The quantum mechanical Hamiltonian doesn't account for "Bremsstrahlung" either. Is this taken care of only in QED?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The quantum mechanical model of a *bound* electron-proton system does not include brehmsstrahlung because the electrons are not small balls orbiting the nucleus.  They exist in stationary energy eigenstates, and do not emit any radiation unless they are making a transition.

At the most simplified level, we could simply couple the classical electromagnetic field to the quantum mechanical model of the atom by inserting the expected values of the charge and current densities into Maxwell's equations.  If one does this, then one finds that the Larmor radiation formula yields a radiated power which depends on $\frac{d}{dt}\langle\mathbf p\rangle$.  For an energy eigenstate, $\langle \mathbf p \rangle=0$, so no radiation is generated.

As a more sophisticated model, one could "second-quantize" the electromagnetic field and couple the single-electron Hilbert space to the photon Fock space.  In this picture, if we restrict our attention to the space of states in which the electron is in an "old" energy eigenstate, then the zero-photon state of the electromagnetic field is an effective ground state, and no brehmsstrahlung photons are emitted.

That being said, such a state is *not* a true eigenstate of the full Hamiltonian if the electron is not in its ground state, and vacuum fluctuations can induce transitions in which the electron moves to a lower energy state and the photon number increases by one - this is [spontaneous emission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spontaneous_emission).

Comment: @J.Murray How do you prove that $\langle P\rangle=0$? I have found an argument based on the generalized Heisenberg inequality, but perhaps there is a more direct argument.

Comment: @ValterMoretti My argument is simply that $\langle p \rangle = \frac{d}{dt}\langle x\rangle$ via the Ehrenfest theorem, and that $\langle x\rangle$ is constant in a stationary state.

Comment: Yes, it is more direct than mine (though Ehrenfest theorem is a disaster when one tries to make it rigorous, subtle problems with domains pop out...)

Comment: @ValterMoretti I admit, I’ve never tried to put it on a rigorous footing. That’s an interesting note that I’ll have to look into.

Comment: In this case I think that everything goes right since one can perform direct computations with the explicit expression of the states. Hence the problem is only theoretical...

Comment: @ValterMoretti I think the OP would like to keep it minimum then.

Comment: @Superfast Sure!!! :)

Comment: Why won't an excited-electron & no photons state evolve into a lower-energy-electron state with a nonzero number of photons? Or did you mean _ground_ state of the electron by "old" energy eigenstate?

Comment: @Ruslan Yes, I was sloppy and inaccurate there. I have updated my answer to clarify what I meant.

Comment: The problem reappears when you get to Boron as the ground state now has an electron in a p state.

Comment: @ValterMoretti Can't you just say that $\langle P \rangle = 0$ by the rotational symmetry of the Hamiltonian, since it's a vector?

Comment: @tpraker It does not work in general since there are energy eigenstate that are not rotationally invariant.

Answer (score 7):

The stability of the hydrogen ground state follows from the Schrödinger equation predicts a lowest bound state, the ground state. A treatment including radiation does not change the fact that there is no lower state to which the system can progress. Of course , the question now is why the Schrödinger equation is correct. To this there appears to be no answer at present.

Comment: "A treatment including radiation does not change the fact that there is no lower state to which the system can progress". Sure,  but *it proves that all levels different from the ground state are instable*...

Comment: @ValterMoretti But that was not the issue here. Also the transition probabilities can simply be found by perturbing the solutions with a plane wave, resulting in Fermi's golden rule. Also I don't understand why a sound a complete answer gets down voted. This may mislead the casual reader and the OP.

Comment: Mine was only a general comment, I did not downvote!

Comment: If you think it necessary I remove my comment, just ask.

Comment: Imagine there is no outer perturbation and the temperature is $T=0$. Then all the orbits should be stable, not just the ground state. But your argument hinges on the idea that the ground state is only stable because there is no state with lower energy in which the electron could transition in by giving off "Bremsstrahlung". This argument may explain why the electron is not collapsing in the core completely and why the ground state is stable, but does not explain for example the stability of the 2p orbital. J. Murrays answer on the other hand shows that also the excited states are stable.

Comment: @TheoreticalMinimum We must be careful here, because excited states *aren't* stable insofar as photons can be emitted during spontaneous emission. My point was to argue against the radiation of photons in a given eigenstate, not against transitions between states.  My update to my answer should clarify this.

Comment: @J.Murray Thank you for this comment. I learned a lot of you the two last days. I thought there could only be transitions if there was an external perturbation (fermis golden rule), but it seems like these transitions can also happen without external influence spontaneously.. So only the ground state is truly stable, I see. Sorry for my misunderstanding @ my2cts

Answer (score 3):

> It's often said that in classical physics a electron-proton system is not stable due to "Bremsstrahlung" and that one instead has to look at it quantum mechanically.
>
> This doesn't make sense to me. The quantum mechanical Hamiltonian doesn't account for "Bremsstrahlung" either. Is this taken care of only in QED?

The reason for the first fact is people know that Bohr gave a convincing argument for why the classical Coulomb-force model can't be correct (because it ignores radiation and its destabilizing effect), and erroneously think that later quantum theory does not have or have solved that problem.

Of course, the standard model of atom in non-relativistic theory does not address or solve the problem at all. There is no radiation in this universally accepted model at all! Bohr's/Schroedinger's model of atom is stable for the same reason non-relativistic Coulomb-force atom model is stable or Newtonian solar system model is stable: no force retardation, no radiation, no relativity is allowed.

When we acknowledge relativistic aspects of EM interaction, the question of which states are "stable"  becomes more involved. Now the Hamiltonian isn't so simple and it isn't even clear we have the right Hamiltonian.

To my knowledge, there is no complete proof of stability of hydrogen atom in QFT allowing all relativistic aspects of EM interaction. Quantum field theory of bound states is hard and most published work makes additional assumptions. There is the Bethe-Salpeter equation which is proclaimed as general, but assumptions are always made to get solutions. Those are: positronium isn't stable but hydrogen atom is (technically "resonance" vs "bound state"). Details such as particle being proton instead of positron play big role here. Is muon-electron system stable? Proton-muon system? Experiments tell us likely answer and we bend the theory to accomodate. There isn't first principles based, dynamical reason for why some are stable and some not.

One often reads about there not being a lower energy state than the ground state as the ultimate reason. But this rests on assumptions about how the complete Hamiltonian looks like. In particular, quadratic Hamiltonian in field strength is almost universally assumed. As is well known, this Hamiltonian poses various problems with infinities. What is less universally known is that this quadratic Hamiltonian is an additional assumption on top of Maxwell's equations and relativity theory and does not derive from them. There may very well be a different way to analyze consequences of EM theory and relativity than using that Hamiltonian.

Comment: I've seen the proof given in college. It holds for s orbitals because L = 0, but fails for higher orbitals so Boron should still be unstable. I said something along the lines of "what they hey, that isn't even fair".

Comment: What do you mean it isn't "fair"?

Comment: They introduce quantum mechanics using this problem, show a solution for the hydrogen atom, claim it's solved, and completely neglect the fact the solution depends on the fact that only S orbitals are occupied in the ground state. Which means they introduced a whole new construct for a problem the new construct doesn't even solve. Boo.